# Hover on containing div not always working

Tags: jquery, html, css

We currently have a global nav with a dropdown submenu nav  that is working fine. We've decided to add an animation on hover to the sub-menu items. However the issue we are currently running into is that the animation won't trigger on the initial  hover.

[Our Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S86x6.png)

How the sub menu is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#services-wrap,#menu-item-99").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#services-wrap,#services-dropdown").show();
    });
    $('#services-wrap,#menu-item-99').mouseleave(function(){
        $("#services-wrap,#services-dropdown").hide();
    });
    $("#product-wrap,#menu-item-102").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#product-wrap,#product-dropdown").show();
    });
    $('#product-wrap,#menu-item-102').mouseleave(function(){
        $("#product-wrap,#product-dropdown").hide();
    });
});
```

Here's an idea of how our sub-menu is set up:

```
<div id="services-wrap">
    <div id="services-dropdown">
        <a href="/services/home-automation/">
            <div id="home-automation">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/va/images/home-automation-bg.png">
                <p>Home<br> Automation</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hover animation css:

```
#services-dropdown a:hover div, #product-dropdown a:hover div{
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    background: #424242;
}

#services-dropdown a:hover img, #product-dropdown a:hover img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transition: all 1.0s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jquery, I found out you have misspelling in typing `services`

```
$("#services-wrap,#servcies-dropdown").show();
```

look at `#servcies-dropdown` 
I think you should write `#services-dropdown`

Comment: Thanks for finding that typo. Wasn't having any problems with the jquery the issue currently is the css for the sub menu items.